# "Sich rausstellen" - no entry in neither Duden nor Dict.cc

Tags: meaning

I've come across the following passage:

> Später hat ***sich*** dann ***rausgestellt***, dass dieser Garten nicht zum
>   Rumlaufen gedacht war, sondern zum Ansehen.

Although it's kind of self-explanatory and the meaning could be deduced from the meaning of the verb without 'sich' as well as the context as

> It ***turned out*** later that this garden was not designed to be walked
>   around, but rather to be beheld.

... but I'm still curious about why neither [Duden](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/ausstellen) nor [Dict.cc](https://www.dict.cc/?s=sich%20ausstellen) have an entry for 'sich rausstellen'.

Comment: same with *Rumlaufen* = *Herumlaufen*.

Comment: there are entries for: https://www.dict.cc/?s=rumlaufen , https://www.dict.cc/?s=rumh%C3%BCpfen , and https://www.dict.cc/?s=rumstehen

Comment: [Duden also lists a lot](https://www.duden.de/suchen/dudenonline/raus) - all have in common that they are colloquial abbreviations for *heraus-* or *hinaus-*.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"sich rausgestellt" is a colloquial version of

> **sich herausstellen**.

Then you can find it in the [Duden](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/herausstellen) and so on. So, "sich ausstellen" is not the long form of this shortened verb.

Comment: Is 'raus' always a colloquial version of 'heraus'? Or is it sometimes used instead of 'aus' for ease of speech flow?

Comment: It's the short version of "heraus". The `'` shows the omitting of "he". I think, it's never used for "aus".

Comment: @Jawad, *raus* is always for *heraus* or *hinaus* (some dialects distinguish the two, others don’t).

Comment: Note: Rausgestellt is normally not written with an apostrophe: https://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/rechtschreibregeln/apostroph#14